Any way to speed up matplotlib FuncAnimation rendering
I am using matplotlib to generate a video for my YouTube channel. It need to be 1920x1080 60 FPS, so lowering the frame rate is not an option.
Here is the code for the animation:
ani = FuncAnimation(
    fig, update, max_frame, init, interval=16, repeat=False, blit=True)

It has an imshow in the background that doesn't change during the animation, so the imshow is not in the update function, hope that improved the performance, and a LineCollection of tens of thousands of segments draw on top of it, which is redrawn every frame by calling line_collection.set_segments(segments).
It takes about 1 hour to generate 1 minute of the video. My computer has a Ryzen 5 5800X3D, not the best CPU for the task but shouldn't be that slow.
I measured the time in each part of the program. It was the internal code in line_collection.set_segments(segments) that consumes 99.9% of the time, not the video encoding, or my code that generates the segments.
I noticed it only uses 1 thread of my CPU, but since it is inside the matplotlib package, I don't know how to change it to multi-thread.

have you considered saving the images and then generating the video? See one of my answers here, if you like this approach, I can post the script that I usually use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78267440/16815358
